# Nesting outlined boxes in math mode (formulas from Laws of Form)

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

I want to type-set some formulas from Spencer-Brown's [Laws of Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Form) using the nested cross formatting, and preferably using math mode, at times inlined into a paragraph. E.g. the following:

[image]

So what I need is the possibility to nest blocks with triangles/lines as delimiters.

How would I go about this without resorting to drawing and embedding a SVG graphic?

Comment: Am I missing something?  You mention "triangles", but I don't see any in the figure, unless that is a particular nomenclature naming convention?

Comment: Well what he calls "crosses". For me these are open triangles. Just what you see in the pasted graphic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's something that could do, with some low level TeX programming.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\CROSS[1]{%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{
      \hrule
      \kern1.5pt
      \hbox{$#1$\,\strut}
    }%
  \vrule
  }\mskip\thickmuskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f &= \CROSS{\CROSS{\CROSS{\CROSS{\dots a}b}a}b} \\
  &= \CROSS{\CROSS{fa}b}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about the modified cross which is condensed re-entry? See an example of its use in Baecker's catjects: https://catjects.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/the-form-of-organization-or-was-it-organizing/

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov I think it's a completely different problem.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. I'm just looking for ways to use the notation. See also here from fig. 6 onwards things get a bit more complicated - http://www.ephemerajournal.org/contribution/shape-things-come-%E2%80%98laws-form%E2%80%99-management-post-growth-economy

Comment: @IvoVelitchkov That requires much more study.

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses various features of the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\Lobj
\newsavebox{\newobj}
\newcommand\LoF[2]{%
  \def\obj{$#1$~$#2$\,}%
  \setlength\Lobj{\widthof{\obj}}%
  \sbox\newobj{\stackon[3pt]{\obj}{\rule{\Lobj}{.3pt}}}%
  \usebox{\newobj}%
  \rule{.3pt}{\ht\newobj}%
}
\begin{document}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\(\stackunder[2ex]{$f$ = \LoF{\LoF{\LoF{\LoF{}{a}}{b}}{a}}{b}}
             {\phantom{$f$} = \LoF{\LoF{}{fa}}{b}}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quite nice and shows the power of your package. I bet a run with `\tracingall` will produce rather different sizes of the log file. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the compliment.  Coming from yourself, it means a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my final version which allows to insert vertical white space. I couldn't figure out how to automatically detect empty horizontal spaces, so I have two macros. The 'echelon' (p.55):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\LoF[2][0]{%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{
      \hrule
      \kern \dimexpr 2pt + #1\dimexpr 2.7pt\relax\relax
      \hbox{$#2$\,\footnotesize\strut}
    }%
  {\vrule depth 1pt}}\mskip7mu
}
\newcommand\LoFN[2][0]{%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{
      \hrule
      \kern \dimexpr 2pt + #1\dimexpr 2.7pt\relax\relax
      \hbox{$#2$\,\footnotesize\strut}
    }%
  {\vrule depth 1pt}}\mskip1mu
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{align*}
&\LoF{\LoF{a}b} \\[0.5ex] % ((a)b)
&= \LoF{\LoF{a}b}\LoF{\LoF{a}b} \\[0.5ex] % ((a)b)((a)b)
&= \LoF{\LoF{a}\LoFN{\LoFN{b}}}\LoF[1]{\LoF{a}b} \\[0.5ex] % (((a)b)a)(((a)b)(b))
&= \LoF{\LoF{\LoF{\LoF{a}b}a}\LoFN{\LoF{\LoF{a}b}\LoFN{b}}} \\[0.5ex] % ((((a)b)a)(((a)b)(b)))
&= \LoF{\LoF{\LoF{\LoF{a}b}a}\LoFN{\LoFN{b}}} \\[0.5ex] % ((((a)b)a)((b)))
&= \LoF{\LoF{\LoF{\LoF{a}b}a}b}  % ((((a)b)a)((b)))
\end{align*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]